# Limit the characters that can be used in a field in formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-formula

I need to limit the characters that can be used in a field to 0-9 and {} and -

I have this working so far, in the Input Validation:

@Matches(@thisvalue; "+{()0-9}")

But how do I go and add the - in this formula?

As usual, thanks fot the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh boy... I guess I was tired last night...  I ended up making work with this:

@Matches(@ThisValue; "+{\-()0-9}")

Hope it might help someone else one day...